# how to render table body only in jsf dataTable

Tags: jsf, datatable

When using a JSF dataTable, is it possible to only render the table body? I know it is possible with `richfaces` with `render="table@body"`, but I can't use it.

This is my code example. The table gets rerendered after a `keyup` event is fired. The problem with this is, everytime this happens the `inputText` where this event is fired loses focus and needs to be reselected manually. Since it is located in the table header, rendering the body only  could fix this behaviour.

```
<h:dataTable id="dataTable" value="#{myBean.employeeList}" var="data">
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">Firstname<br/>
        <h:inputText id="searchFirstname" value="#{myBean.searchStringFirstname}"    >
            <f:ajax listener="#{myBean.searchStringKeyUpListener}" event="keyup" render="dataTable" />
        </h:inputText>
        </f:facet>

        #{data.person.firstname}

    </h:column>
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">Lastname<br/>
        <h:inputText id="searchLastname" value="#{myBean.searchStringLastname}"> </h:inputText>
        </f:facet>
        #{data.person.lastname}
    </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>
```

Comment: afaik, you can't. Rerendereing a datatable, even if it is just the body,  on each key-up is not something I'd implement. But maybe you can set some global javascript variable on focus of the input with e.g. the id of the input, put some javascript before the datatable and re-render that to. In the javascript, read the global variable and do a focus of the input.

Comment: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/filter.xhtml